# Error when exporting android project when library added

Tags: android, eclipse, andengine

Since a couple of month ago I've been working with Android developing in Eclipse and AndEngine. I haven't had any problems to export my project until a couple of weeks ago when I suddenly got an error when I tried to export my project. The error only occurs when AndEngine (or any of its extensions) is added in the project's library. I have searched for a solution day and night now and I hope someone can help me! I do not know if it’s only AndEngine or if I can’t export just because I have something added in the library.

I have installed Eclipse in two completely different systems - one Windows, the other Linux Mint - no one works!

This is how I do:

I create a new android project, including an activity. I try to export it - it works. After that, I add AndEngine through properties>Android>Library. I try to export - I get an error - "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" in Windows 7 and in Linux Eclipse crashes.

In Linux Eclipse creates a log-file, but I'm not skilled enough to interpret it myself ... :-/

Perhaps it is something with the latest updates of the Android sdk or something like that ... I do not know. And the strange thing is that it I seem to be the only one getting this error - on two different systems! Am I doing anything wrong or what is this?!

If anyone would like to help I would be so happy I do not know what to do!
Johan

Here is the error log that I got:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f7ab35c053e, pid=2405, tid=140164621686528
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b24
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.11.1
# Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, package 6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu3
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0x453e]  Java_java_util_zip_ZipEntry_initFields+0xc3e
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f7ab4a2b800):  JavaThread "ModalContext" [_thread_in_native, id=2683, stack(0x00007f7a9e6c5000,0x00007f7a9e7c6000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGBUS: si_errno=0, si_code=2 (BUS_ADRERR), si_addr=0x00007f7a9ddb4124

Registers:
RAX=0x00007f7a34000fa0, RBX=0x00007f7a9ddb4107, RCX=0x00007f7a34000040, RDX=0x00007f7a34000020
RSP=0x00007f7a9e7c3310, RBP=0x00007f7a9e7c3350, RSI=0x00007f7a34000038, RDI=0x0000000000000003
R8 =0x00007f7a34048100, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x00007f7ab06f9d78, R11=0x00007f7ab9ef44d0
R12=0x00007f7a34000fa0, R13=0x00007f7a9e7c33c0, R14=0x00007f7a34007e50, R15=0x00007f7a340087f8
RIP=0x00007f7ab35c053e, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f7a9e7c3310)
0x00007f7a9e7c3310:   00007f7a9e7c3330 00007f7ab95b7b71
0x00007f7a9e7c3320:   00007f7a34007e50 00007f7a34007e50
0x00007f7a9e7c3330:   000000008433e918 00007f7a9e7c33c0
0x00007f7a9e7c3340:   0000000000000000 00007f7a340087f8
0x00007f7a9e7c3350:   00007f7a9e7c33a0 00007f7ab35c0dea
0x00007f7a9e7c3360:   00007f7ab4a2b800 00007f7a34004cc0
0x00007f7a9e7c3370:   00007f7ab4a2b800 00007f7ab4a2b9d0
0x00007f7a9e7c3380:   00007f7a9e7c33c0 0000000000000029
0x00007f7a9e7c3390:   00007f7a9e7c3818 00007f7a9e7c33c0
0x00007f7a9e7c33a0:   00007f7a9e7c3800 00007f7ab35bf4a9
0x00007f7a9e7c33b0:   0000002900000000 00007f7a34007e50
0x00007f7a9e7c33c0:   65646e612f67726f 75612f656e69676e
0x00007f7a9e7c33d0:   657361422f6f6964 746e456f69647541
0x00007f7a9e7c33e0:   73616c632e797469 0000000000000073
0x00007f7a9e7c33f0:   00000000f9b29a28 00007f7a9e7c33f8
0x00007f7a9e7c3400:   00000000dc3bf5b2 00007f7a9e7c3450
0x00007f7a9e7c3410:   00000000dc3bfeb8 0000000000000000
0x00007f7a9e7c3420:   00000000dc3bf5d8 0000000000000000
0x00007f7a9e7c3430:   00007f7a9e7c3498 00007f7ab05c1a82
0x00007f7a9e7c3440:   00007f7ab05c1a82 00000000dbd92860
0x00007f7a9e7c3450:   0000000000000002 00007f7a9e7c3458
0x00007f7a9e7c3460:   00000000dc3bf7d3 00007f7a9e7c34c8
0x00007f7a9e7c3470:   00000000dc3bfeb8 0000000000000000
0x00007f7a9e7c3480:   00000000dc3bf830 0000000000000000
0x00007f7a9e7c3490:   00007f7a9e7c34c0 00007f7a9e7c3510
0x00007f7a9e7c34a0:   00007f7ab05c1e8d 00000000f9b29f90
0x00007f7a9e7c34b0:   0000000000000002 0000000000000002
0x00007f7a9e7c34c0:   00007f7a9e7c3530 00007f7ab05c196e
0x00007f7a9e7c34d0:   00007f7a9e7c34d0 00007f7ab05c196e
0x00007f7a9e7c34e0:   00000000f9a860c8 00000000f9ac9b70
0x00007f7a9e7c34f0:   00007f7a9e7c34f0 00000000dc3b1448
0x00007f7a9e7c3500:   00007f7a9e7c3568 00007f7ab05c196e 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f7ab35c053e)
0x00007f7ab35c051e:   c7 00 00 00 00 00 48 c7 40 30 00 00 00 00 48 c7
0x00007f7ab35c052e:   40 28 00 00 00 00 8b 1b 49 2b 5e 28 49 03 5e 18
0x00007f7ab35c053e:   44 0f b6 7b 1d 0f b6 43 1c 0f b6 53 0c 0f b6 4b
0x00007f7ab35c054e:   0e 44 0f b6 6b 1f 41 c1 e7 08 41 09 c7 0f b6 43 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007f7a34000fa0 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007f7a9ddb4107 is an unknown value
RCX=0x00007f7a34000040 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007f7a34000020 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f7a9e7c3310 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f7ab4a2b800
RBP=0x00007f7a9e7c3350 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f7ab4a2b800
RSI=0x00007f7a34000038 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00007f7a34048100 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x00007f7ab06f9b90 [CodeBlob (0x00007f7ab06f9b90)]
Framesize: 10
R11=0x00007f7ab9ef44d0: <offset 0x1814d0> in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 at 0x00007f7ab9d73000
R12=0x00007f7a34000fa0 is an unknown value
R13=0x00007f7a9e7c33c0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f7ab4a2b800
R14=0x00007f7a34007e50 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007f7a340087f8 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00007f7a9e6c5000,0x00007f7a9e7c6000],  sp=0x00007f7a9e7c3310,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libzip.so+0x453e]  Java_java_util_zip_ZipEntry_initFields+0xc3e
C  [libzip.so+0x4dea]  ZIP_GetEntry+0xba
C  [libzip.so+0x34a9]  Java_java_util_zip_ZipFile_getEntry+0x119
J  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(JLjava/lang/String;Z)J
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream;+34
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;)Ljava/io/InputStream;+5
j  com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(Ljava/io/File;)Z+118
j  com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(Ljava/io/File;Z)Z+48
j  com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process()Z+15
j  com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Ljava/lang/String;)Z+18
j  com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles()Z+100
j  com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Lcom/android/dx/command/dexer/Main$Arguments;)I+76
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x4afabf]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x29f
V  [libjvm.so+0x4aeef5]  JavaCalls::call(JavaValue*, methodHandle, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x25
V  [libjvm.so+0x6a8cc7]  Reflection::invoke(instanceKlassHandle, methodHandle, Handle, bool, objArrayHandle, BasicType, objArrayHandle, bool, Thread*)+0x667
V  [libjvm.so+0x6ab12b]  Reflection::invoke_method(oopDesc*, Handle, objArrayHandle, Thread*)+0x16b
V  [libjvm.so+0x4f4b08]  JVM_InvokeMethod+0x148
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Collection;ZLjava/io/PrintStream;Ljava/io/PrintStream;)I+309
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaProject;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)V+138
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;Ljava/io/File;Ljava/security/PrivateKey;Ljava/security/cert/X509Certificate;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+780
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Z+269
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(Lcom/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/wizards/export/ExportWizard;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Z+2
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+10
j  org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run()V+15
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x4afabf]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x29f
V  [libjvm.so+0x4aeef5]  JavaCalls::call(JavaValue*, methodHandle, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x25
V  [libjvm.so+0x4af3f3]  JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, KlassHandle, symbolHandle, symbolHandle, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x1a3
V  [libjvm.so+0x4af51f]  JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Handle, KlassHandle, symbolHandle, symbolHandle, Thread*)+0x4f
V  [libjvm.so+0x4e4fd6]  thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*)+0x86
V  [libjvm.so+0x74c098]  JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0x58
V  [libjvm.so+0x64bbb2]  java_start(Thread*)+0x112

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(JLjava/lang/String;Z)J
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream;+34
j  java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(Ljava/util/zip/ZipEntry;)Ljava/io/InputStream;+5
j  com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(Ljava/io/File;)Z+118
j  com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(Ljava/io/File;Z)Z+48
j  com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process()Z+15
j  com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Ljava/lang/String;)Z+18
j  com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles()Z+100
j  com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Lcom/android/dx/command/dexer/Main$Arguments;)I+76
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Collection;ZLjava/io/PrintStream;Ljava/io/PrintStream;)I+309
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaProject;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)V+138
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;Ljava/io/File;Ljava/security/PrivateKey;Ljava/security/cert/X509Certificate;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+780
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Z+269
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(Lcom/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/wizards/export/ExportWizard;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)Z+2
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V+10
j  org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run()V+15
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f7a200d1800 JavaThread "Worker-12" [_thread_blocked, id=2718, stack(0x00007f7a9e298000,0x00007f7a9e399000)]
=>0x00007f7ab4a2b800 JavaThread "ModalContext" [_thread_in_native, id=2683, stack(0x00007f7a9e6c5000,0x00007f7a9e7c6000)]
  0x00007f7a38001000 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2448, stack(0x00007f7a97897000,0x00007f7a97998000)]
  0x00007f7ab4761000 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2447, stack(0x00007f7a9d17a000,0x00007f7a9d27b000)]
  0x00007f7a20001000 JavaThread "Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=2441, stack(0x00007f7a9da2a000,0x00007f7a9db2b000)]
  0x00007f7a3008f800 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=2440, stack(0x00007f7a9db2b000,0x00007f7a9dc2c000)]
  0x00007f7a30081800 JavaThread "Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=2439, stack(0x00007f7a9dc2c000,0x00007f7a9dd2d000)]
  0x00007f7a44019800 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_in_native, id=2437, stack(0x00007f7a9e399000,0x00007f7a9e49a000)]
  0x00007f7ab443f000 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2436, stack(0x00007f7a9de20000,0x00007f7a9df21000)]
  0x00007f7a4c040000 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=2431, stack(0x00007f7a9fafb000,0x00007f7a9fbfc000)]
  0x00007f7a4c03b800 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2430, stack(0x00007f7a9fbfc000,0x00007f7a9fcfd000)]
  0x00007f7a4c015800 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2428, stack(0x00007f7a9fdfe000,0x00007f7a9feff000)]
  0x00007f7ab41e4000 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2427, stack(0x00007f7a9feff000,0x00007f7aa0000000)]
  0x00007f7ab41fd800 JavaThread "State Data Manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2426, stack(0x00007f7aa4021000,0x00007f7aa4122000)]
  0x00007f7ab41c2800 JavaThread "Framework Active Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=2425, stack(0x00007f7aa4122000,0x00007f7aa4223000)]
  0x00007f7ab40a5800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2421, stack(0x00007f7aae3bd000,0x00007f7aae4be000)]
  0x00007f7ab40a3800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2420, stack(0x00007f7aae4be000,0x00007f7aae5bf000)]
  0x00007f7ab40a0800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2419, stack(0x00007f7aae5bf000,0x00007f7aae6c0000)]
  0x00007f7ab4092800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2418, stack(0x00007f7aae6c0000,0x00007f7aae7c1000)]
  0x00007f7ab4080000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2417, stack(0x00007f7aaeea4000,0x00007f7aaefa5000)]
  0x00007f7ab407e000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2416, stack(0x00007f7aaefa5000,0x00007f7aaf0a6000)]
  0x00007f7ab4008000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=2406, stack(0x00007f7aba858000,0x00007f7aba959000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00007f7ab4077800 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f7aaf0a6000,0x00007f7aaf1a7000] [id=2415]
  0x00007f7ab40a8000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f7aae2bc000,0x00007f7aae3bd000] [id=2422]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 54656K, used 5004K [0x00000000f8000000, 0x00000000fc550000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 38720K, 7% used [0x00000000f8000000,0x00000000f82a96f8,0x00000000fa5d0000)
  from space 15936K, 14% used [0x00000000fb5c0000,0x00000000fb7f9c88,0x00000000fc550000)
  to   space 16128K, 0% used [0x00000000fa5d0000,0x00000000fa5d0000,0x00000000fb590000)
 PSOldGen        total 79168K, used 52829K [0x00000000e8000000, 0x00000000ecd50000, 0x00000000f8000000)
  object space 79168K, 66% used [0x00000000e8000000,0x00000000eb3974d0,0x00000000ecd50000)
 PSPermGen       total 130432K, used 71024K [0x00000000d8000000, 0x00000000dff60000, 0x00000000e8000000)
  object space 130432K, 54% used [0x00000000d8000000,0x00000000dc55c010,0x00000000dff60000)

Code Cache  [0x00007f7ab05bc000, 0x00007f7ab0e8c000, 0x00007f7ab35bc000)
 total_blobs=2339 nmethods=1742 adapters=550 free_code_cache=41736384 largest_free_block=59712

Dynamic libraries:
I had to remove this part ... only 30 000 characters allowed

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms40m -Xmx384m -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
java_command: /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash -launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse -name Eclipse --launcher.library /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.dist/eclipse_1408.so -startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar --launcher.overrideVmargs -exitdata f8005 -vm /usr/bin/java -vmargs -Xms40m -Xmx384m -Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.dist.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
USERNAME=johan
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/../lib/amd64
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0.0

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x7842c0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x7842c0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x648540], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00001000, sa_flags=0x10000000
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x648540], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x648540], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x6486f0], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x64b210], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x64b210], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x64b210], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x64b210], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:LinuxMint 13 (maya)
uname:Linux 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.15 NPTL 2.15 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 127501, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:1.69 1.02 0.47

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       16337780 kB
MemFree:        14311524 kB
Buffers:           75920 kB
Cached:           693268 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          1111276 kB
Inactive:         608384 kB
Active(anon):     960444 kB
Inactive(anon):   183040 kB
Active(file):     150832 kB
Inactive(file):   425344 kB
Unevictable:          96 kB
Mlocked:              96 kB
SwapTotal:      16678908 kB
SwapFree:       16678908 kB
Dirty:              5948 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        951204 kB
Mapped:           124272 kB
Shmem:            192228 kB
Slab:              74556 kB
SReclaimable:      43580 kB
SUnreclaim:        30976 kB
KernelStack:        3008 kB
PageTables:        20856 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    24847796 kB
Committed_AS:    2139640 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      389744 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359345424 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       71668 kB
DirectMap2M:    16615424 kB


CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 16337780k(14311524k free), swap 16678908k(16678908k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_24-b24), built on Apr 21 2012 01:49:27 by "buildd" with gcc 4.6.3

time: Sun Jun 24 16:12:57 2012
elapsed time: 194 seconds
```

I just want to make a thing clear:

I can run the application on, for example, my cellphone, via Eclipse - it's the exporting with keystore and that, that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you added the JAR files to your lib folder (inside the project) and then added it to the Build Path by right clicking it and selecting Build Path > Add to Build Path

Comment: AndEngine is an Android Library Project, you must import the existing project into Eclipse first, before adding AndEngine through `properties -> Android -> Library`.

Comment: @Blaine Anderson I am quite new to this forum can I send it in a  pm or something, since it is quite long?

Comment: @Cruceo I have added them to Eclipse as discribed in [link](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6131C7A9DDCF959A&annotation_id=annotation_439676&src_vid=JVmuKPHAC8k&feature=iv) - ie. no JAR:s. Also, as I do a completely new project, I do not think a misplaced JAR is the problem, but I do not know?

Comment: @yorkw I do import them into Eclipse, as discribed in the youtube video, using GIT, and AndEngine is shown in the list where you can choose library projects, so it should be right, I think?

Comment: Don't worry about the length, just highlight the code and press "command K" (depending on your comp). It will automatically "frame" your code and create a scroll box.

Comment: @Blaine Anderson I added the crash log in the original message, since I coudn't do it as a comment ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but I seem to have found another solution.  Generally, I found that Eclipse would either crash completely or just freeze/hang if I try to export a project that has a dependency on another library project.  I've seen this several times with both my own library projects as well as 3rd party ones.

The simple solution I found is turning off automatic build.  That is, compete everything, then just before doing "export", uncheck "Build Automatically" under the "Project" menu - and export as usual.

Answer (score 3):

Today I stumbled upon exactly the same problem and I also coulnd't find a solution to it anywhere. It is strange because I have never had this problem before and I have already worked with AndEngine many times. I tried a couple of different things and one of them totally solved the problem although I have no idea why.

Solution:

1. Don't add the AndEngine to libraries list (through properties -> Android -> Library)
2. Copy the "libs" directory from AndEngine to your application.
3. Copy the "andengine.jar" from AndEngine's "bin" directory to some directory in your application.
4. Close the AndEngine project. You don't need it to do the export anymore.
5. Right click on your project. Go to: "Properties -> Libraries -> Add JARs" and add the JAR you just copied.
6. Go to Properties -> "Libraries -> Order and Export" and make sure the JAR file you just added is selected.

It would be great if someone could tell us why this solves the problem and if there are any better solutions.

Comment: Thanks You saved my day. After 4 hours of headaches you made my day :)